# using LINQ inside Function Task.Run();

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, devexpress, .net-4.8

I have a Windows Forms application that I'm developing, and I'm trying to optimize the code for better performance. I've tried using `Task.Run`, but I encountered two issues.

```
var customerGroupMembers = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(DataHelper.DbContexth.CustomerGroupMembers.ToList);
var customerGroups = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(DataHelper.DbContexth.CustomerGroups.ToList);
var employees = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(DataHelper.DbContexth.Employees.ToList);
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(customerGroupMembers,customerGroups, employees);
repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit6.DataSource = customerGroups.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit7.DataSource = employees.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit5.DataSource = customerGroupMembers.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This line does not wait for data to continue

```
  repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit5.DataSource = customerGroupMembers.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

If i use

```
 _ = customerGroupMembers.ContinueWith(task => repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit5.DataSource = task.Result);
```

It gives me incorrect context
And if I use

```
var customerGroups = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=>DataHelper.DbContexth.CustomerGroups.ToList());
```

It gives me an Error

Comment: _"It gives me an Error"_ - what error exactly? What is `DataHelper.DbContexth`?

Comment: If you are trying to optimize, step 1 should be to *profile* your code. If you are doing database operations you should make sure your queries are as efficient as possible. You should not request all rows from a database unless you are certain there are fairly few rows, and if there are only a few rows, why is it slow?

Comment: Unless you have created your own implementation of an ORM, most packages have already optimized thread efficiency much more than you or I are able to on our own.  Simply `await`ing any database calls should give you indistinguishable performance (on the order of milliseconds depending on where your connection is).

Comment: Also be aware that you cannot modify a Windows Form control from a thread OTHER than the GUI thread that created it.

Comment: Formatting error with data source and i want to fetch all rows

Comment: Why aren't you using normal `async`/`await` on your data? Why aren't you calling `Invoke` to send the data to each `DataSource`? It looks like you're just doing a couple of things wrong and that's giving you all the grief.